# replace web.config in asp.net core vs 2017 on publish

Tags: asp.net-core, csproj, visual-studio-2017

i'm trying to replace the web.config with the production version.

I have the production version in `~\production\web.config` (tilda as the root of my project folder).

I found this in the migration document

```
<ItemGroup>

  <Content Include="Views\**\*" PackagePath="%(Identity)" />

  <None Include="notes.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToOutputDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

  <None Include="publishnotes.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToPublishDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried to use something like this

```
<ItemGroup>   
     <None Include="_production\web.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

but in this way the folder and the file both will copy to the publish directory. it's a combination of mapping and publish and unfortunately  the documentation is suffering from lack of example, so i tried to guess/figure it out  by combining the mapping example with the publish.

first i tried this:

```
<None Include="_production\web.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"  PackagePath="in/web.test"/>
```

so i was expecting to see a `in` folder in the publish directory but didn't.

i tried

```
<None Include="_production\web.config" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always"  PublishPath="in/web.test"/>
```

but didn't worked as well.

you can find the migration document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most right way, but you may achieve this using `Copy` task directly:

```
<Target Name="CustomScript" AfterTargets="GeneratePublishRuntimeConfigurationFile">
    <Copy SourceFiles="_production\web.config" 
          DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"
          SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
</Target>
```

- `AfterTargets="GeneratePublishRuntimeConfigurationFile"` as we want to do replacement only after default `web.config` will be generated in publish folder
- `OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true"` - without this `web.config` cannnot be replaced

Comment: thanks it works, but it also copy the `_production` folder

Comment: I found out that the problem is the file set as content. i right clicked and set it to none, so your solution worked perfectly