# How to pre-configure my .NET Core 1.1 app's published web.config file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I have an MVC project that is targeting `.NETCoreApp 1.1`. When I publish the project, a `web.config` file is created for me. I want the created `web.config` to contain a few rewrite rules.

I've tried adding a `web.config` file to the project root, but every publish attempt contains the same generic, mostly empty configuration file. Where/how do I get the publish process to include a web.config that contains my extra information?

**Edit:**

It looks like this may not be an issue with dotnet core's publish. This may be an issue to how I've configured my TeamCity build.

- Works when using a local folder publish from VS 2017
- Works running the following CLI command: (same as what's used in TC)

  - `dotnet publish .\{{projectName}}.csproj --configuration Staging --output C:\new-output-dir\`

Comment: This solution seems to work for copying an included build file and pasting it over the automatically generated one in the root: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742822/replace-web-config-in-asp-net-core-vs-2017-on-publish

Still hoping to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: I have `web.config` in project root with custom rewrite rules, and after running `dotnet publish` I see correctly updated `web.config` in publish dir (only <aspNetCore...> updated) with all my custom XML unchanged. What's your way to publish?

Answer (score 2):

@Dmitry's comment lead me down the right path.

I hopped into TeamCity's build logs to see what command was being executed to publish my app. It looked similar to:

`dotnet publish .\{{projectName}}.csproj --configuration Staging --output C:\new-output-dir\`

TeamCity was re-using the output directory for each build, and by default the previous `web.config`s that had been generated weren't being overwritten with the new one that contained the rewrite rules.

**Two possible solutions:**

- Use a new output directory per build
- Clear or force overwrite files in existing output directories

  - [Use `dotnet clean` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean)

Resources for learning more:

- [Official `dotnet publish` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)
- [Quick notes on `dotnet publish` command](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/dotnet-publish.md])

Comment: I discovered the same issue when debugging my problem. if you mark your `web.config` as "Copy to Output Directory" to "Always", it should take the current file, not what's in the destination. more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51272873/218136

Answer (score -1):

The web.config file in .net core is only used for IIS to know what *.exe to load. You need to use the app.config file to configure all your rules, etc. If you notice the mvc project is now a console app.

Comment: That may be true, but the IIS rewrite module seems to read the rewrite rules well enough?

Comment: I agree, managing IIS via config will still use web.config as it's source. Sorry, I'm not much help here. I'm still interested in knowing the answer though.