# How to define custom web.config in .Net Core 2 for IIS publish?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

VS will generate (and override) a web.config file as part of publishing to IIS. I have various items I need to include in the file (like extending the file upload max size limit, redirecting to HTTPS, etc.). I am currently having to copy and paste the contents into the file after every publish.

Is there a way to define the contents of the web.config file that Visual Studio generates when publishing a .NET Core 2 web app for IIS?

Comment: Add a ˋweb.config` to your project.

Comment: @Lex Li If I've tried that. Even with Build Action = Content, VS doesn't publish it. Or maybe it does and then overwrites it.

Comment: At least `dotnet publish` does not overwrite it. VS is not a must here to publish a web app.

Comment: @Lex Li I guess that's an option but I'm using publish to IIS in VS so I don't have to copy files manually. I wonder if there is a way to do it using VS Publish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got back to this and wound up using a transform:

1. Create a web.release.config file in the root of the project
2. Set that file's properties to Build Action = None so it doesn't get copied directly to the destination folder
3. Use the transformation syntax to define the sections that need to be inserted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location>
    <system.webServer>
      <security xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
      <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <rules>
          <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <modules xdt:Transform="Insert" runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 13):

not sure if you solved this, but if anyone else runs across this problem, I had this issue and finally went looking for the source code for the transform task. it contains some logging, so I ran the `dotnet publish` with a `/v:n` parameter, which sets the logging verbosity to "normal":

```
dotnet publish src\MyProject -o ..\..\publish /v:n
```

when I ran this, I saw this in the output:

```
_TransformWebConfig:
  No web.config found. Creating 'C:\Development\MyProject\publish\web.config'
```

even though there is a web.config in the project. I changed the properties of the web.config **"Copy to Output Directory"** to **"Always"**, and now the web.config in my project gets merged with the auto-generated contents.

my csproj now has this in it:

```
    <None Include="web.config">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
```

and the publish output has:

```
_TransformWebConfig:
  Updating web.config at 'C:\Development\MyProject\publish\web.config'
```

**NOTE:** if you are publishing to an existing directory that already has web.config in it, it will update that file. (i.e., an old publish). if you don't specify an output directory, it will publish to something like `/bin/Debug/net471/publish/`, which may have old files in it.

**NOTE2:** you still need the `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` attribute on the Project node in your csproj file, or it won't even bother looking for Web.configs.

for reference, here is the task source code: 
https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/master/src/Publish/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks/Tasks/TransformWebConfig.cs

Comment: To easily edit the csproj file in VS2019, right click on the project name and then click "Edit Project File". Then look for the web.config entry in an <ItemGroup> block.