# Setting MaxURLLength of HTTPGet Call in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server

Hi I need to update the maxurllength of asp.net core service that is running on a service fabric cluster using kestral server.
Looking at other solutions people have recomended making changes to registry and web.config but in case of Kestral server running asp.net core on service fabric we dont have any web.config file.
[Kestral server limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserverlimits?view=aspnetcore-1.1) does not expose a way of doing this either. Is it possible to do so in ASP.net core?

Update:

I was using service fabric reverse proxy to access the service and a sample problematic URL is :

```
http://localhost:19081/{appname}/{servicename}/test-backend/v1.0/mode/1/context/5e2550ec-539a-4ea0-81b5-f783ce3f7c48/file/60917927-8a7d-4702-93e4-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
```

The last URL segment which is some encoded string is the issue.

Comment: What do you want to set it to?

Comment: a value like 1096 maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 1.1 [`KestrelServerLimits.MaxRequestLineSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestlinesize) should be what you are looking for.

For ASP.NET Core 2.1 [`KestrelServerLimits.MaxRequestLineSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxrequestlinesize?view=aspnetcore-2.1) should be what you are looking for.

The default on both is 8Kb, so that should be much bigger than the default 2083 Url length provided by chrome and other browsers.

If you are exposing your APIs using the Service Fabric Reverse Proxy, the problem should be the Reverse Proxy and not Kestrel.

Service Fabric Reverse Proxy uses the windows HTTP.sys driver to expose the http endpoints, by [default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows) this is limited to 260 chars per segment (values between each slash '/'), if this is the case, you should configure your machine with other values instead, in this case, you should set the value for `UrlSegmentMaxLength`

To do that you have to create a **DWORD** called `UrlSegmentMaxLength` under the following registry key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters`
and set it to a number between 0 and 32,766.

I think if you provide the real problem, we could help with a better solution.

Comment: Great catch. I was using service fabric reverse proxy and thats where its breaking. So the kestrel server is not limiting me the reverse proxy is because one of the URL segment exceed max limit of 260. I'll give a try to changing the registry and let you know if it works. Cheers :)

Comment: KerstelServerLimits works if you are hosting it on Kerstel. E.g. Azure App Services running on IIS at this moment and using Reverse Proxy to host .NET Core apps. So Kerstel config won't have any affect in that case...

Answer (score 0):

Just one side note: **.NET Core apps can be hosted with IIS** as well. In that case a Reverse Proxy talks to Kerstel. Also during "dotnet publish" a web.config created for this case to make IIS work with .NET Core.

So in this scenario it means you have to set up these hosting level changes in both places. I had a lot of problem with the configuration of IIS in a .NET Core project unit found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223147/how-to-define-custom-web-config-in-net-core-2-for-iis-publish/59743789#59743789) post.